# Vim python-mode plugin picks up system python and not anaconda

Tags: vim, python-mode

When i use python-mode it uses my system (mac python), I have anaconda installed and want Vim to autocomplete etc with that version of python

As it stands now, python-mode will only autocomplete modules in from system python and not any other modules e.g. pandas that is installed in the anaconda distro.

thanx
Tobie

Comment: You need to recompile vim to use that version of python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not trivial.  Python-mode uses the Python interpreter Vim is linked against; you'll have to recompile Vim and link it against Anaconda.